# Workaround for Firefox's lack of window.event?

Tags: javascript, firefox, events

I have been caught off guard by Firefox's lack of window.event ... namely

```
<script>
function clicked()
{ 
 console.log(event);
}
</script>

<div onclick = "clicked()">Whatever</div>
```

will work in pretty much every modern browser, yet "event" will be undefined in Firefox, where we have to explicitly write

```
<script>
function clicked(event)
{ 
 console.log(event);
}
</script>

<div onclick = "clicked(event)">Whatever</div>
```

Is there any viable workaround to access the event object in Firefox without having to make it explicit as a function parameter?

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? `window.event` is completely non-standard.

Comment: ?? You already have the "work-around", passing the event object to the handler. The global event object is not standard, that shouldn't be used in the first place.

Comment: Sometimes companies inherit code that they want to just keep barely functional through hacks, while a complete rewrite is done in parallel.

Comment: @AlexanderOMara I don't really agree with the duplicate close reason here. The original question asks for the reason why, while this one asks for a workaround.

Comment: Yes I found the "why" question but it didn't provide a workaround (I suppose spreading bad practices only help keeping the ugliness alive in browsers, but sometimes it's a necessary evil of the business type). Not a duplicate indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an ugly hack, based on the assumption that all event listeners will ultimately be registered by the [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method. The "solution" below changes `EventTarget`'s prototype (yuck!) so as to wrap all event listeners in a method that will assign the event to `window.event` before delegating to the actual listener.

```js
const addEventListener = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;

EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(name, handler) {
  addEventListener.call(this, name, function(event) {
    window.event = event;
    
    handler(event);
  })
};

function clicked() {
  // just demonstrating that window.event is set
  console.log(window.event.target.innerHTML);
}

document.getElementById('one').addEventListener('click', clicked);
document.getElementById('two').addEventListener('click', clicked);
```

```html
<button id="one">Test 1</button>
<button id="two">Test 2</button>
```

The above just illustrates a possible approach and is largely untested. Your mileage may vary.

---

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments, this will not work for event handlers bound through the `on...` HTML attributes or assigned using the `Element.on...` properties.

An alternative (and arguably safer) approach could be to use event capturing on the document element, and perform the assignment to `window.event` there.

```js
document.documentElement.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  window.event = event;
}, true);

function clicked() {
  // just demonstrating that window.event is set
  console.log(window.event.target.innerHTML);
}

document.getElementById('one').addEventListener('click', clicked);
document.getElementById('two').onclick = clicked;
```

```html
<button id="one">Test 1</button>
<button id="two">Test 2</button>
<button id="three" onclick="clicked()">Test 3</button>
```

Comment: Horrendous and horrendously working. Good enough to keep this abomination alive for a while.

Comment: No, HTMLEventAttribute do not end in `EventTarget#addEventListener`. This would *work* only for events registered through this method.

Comment: @Kaiido Please clarify. What do you mean by HTMLEventAttribute? Can you provide an example?

Comment: HTML `on<...>` attributes.

Comment: @Kaiido I have those in the snippet above.

Comment: And your snippet throws in FF. https://i.stack.imgur.com/U026U.png

Comment: @Kaiido Yup, you're right. Should've checked :)

Comment: Yes, when writing a browser-specific workaround, that sounds like a good idea to test it at least on said browser...

Comment: @Kaiido Point taken.