# mouseenter and mouseleave event listeners on document not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript

The following code works correctly in Chrome but not in Firefox. In Chrome, when I move my mouse outside and inside the browser, there will be some output in the console, but that is not the case in Firefox. My Firefox version is 85.0.2. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
document.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  console.log("mouseenter");
});
document.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  console.log("mouseleave");
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since your document does not contain anything, there is technically nothing for the mouse to enter or leave

Comment: @Rojo As suggested by mplungjan, I added some css and updated the question. The current code still does not work in Firefox. There is nothing in Firefox's console.

Answer (score 3):

Try `document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {})`

[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Try to give dimensions to the page and use body instead

```js
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  console.log("mouseenter");
});
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  console.log("mouseleave");
});
```

```css
html, body { width: 100vw; height:100vh; background-color:red; }
```

A test of the event listener

```js
const addEventListener = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;

EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(name, handler) {
  addEventListener.call(this, name, function(event) {
    window.event = event;

    handler(event);
  })
};

function showEvent(e) {
  // just demonstrating that window.event is set
  console.log(e.type);
}


document.addEventListener('mouseenter', showEvent);
document.addEventListener('mouseleave', showEvent);
document.addEventListener('mouseover', showEvent);
document.addEventListener('mouseout', showEvent);
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47786133/workaround-for-firefoxs-lack-of-window-event
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, but I wonder if it's possible to make those event listeners also work on `document` instead of `body` because it works well in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Comment: @Hao it's working for me on Firefox 85. Chrome can handle `document.body` too. Firefox will not handle `document` in any way as of right now.

Comment: @Hao So mouseover and out works. Difference is in the event bubbling

Answer (score 1):

It may be because the page isn't fully loaded:

```js
window.onload = (event) => {
  const element = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

  element.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    console.log("mouseenter");
  });
  
  element.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    console.log("mouseleave");
  });
};
```

Live demo: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GNQZGHTD6CC9

worked on Firefox.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP wants the **entire document** to check for mouse events. That link only logged when the text hovered (Firefox 85)

Comment: Yes, I wonder whether those event listeners can work on `document`.

Comment: I see, but for me, adding the event listener for `body` would make more sense than `document` as `document` is an object while `body` is a DOM element

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Your code is identical to mine except you do it on load.